# Java 8 Group a List by attribute in a place

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am a longtime Java developer, but am curious how I would do the following, and I have not found something like this done online using Java 8, though I'm sure its possible.

Say I have a list of objects, and each object in the list has a name. There are three possible names: "Jack", "Terry", "Jon", though 100s of objects.
In Java 8, with one line of code, how can I 'sort' the array such that all the Terry's will be first, followed by all the Jacks, followed by all the Jons?

Comment: With Guava you can do `list.sort(Ordering.explicit("Terry", "Jack", "Jon").onResultOf(MyClass::getName));`.

Comment: The phrases "in-place" and "with Java8" (and the corresponding answers) seem to be contradictive: If you want to sort in-place, you cannot use streams. Otherwise, it boils down to `Collections.sort` with the comparator that e.g. Pankaj Singhal showed in his answer. (The answer uses streams, so it's not in-place...)

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to define sort order using List. Otherwise this is same as suggested by Pankaj Singhal:

```
    Map<String,Integer> order = Map.of("Terry", 0, "Jack", 1, "Jon", 2);
    sortedList = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> order.getOrDefault(i.getName(), MAX_VALUE)))
            .collect(toList());
```

or, if inplace sorting is required:

```
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(i -> order.getOrDefault(i.getName(), MAX_VALUE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the following list represent the sort order:

```
List<String> sortOrder = Arrays.asList("Terry","Jack","Jon");
```

We can sort the elements as follows:

```
MyClass[] sorted = Arrays.stream(initial)
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> sortOrder.indexOf(o.name)))
                        .toArray(MyClass[]::new);
```

Output:

```
[Terry, Terry, Terry, Jack, Jon, Jon]
```